# How to src to a file in a folder within a folder

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm pretty new to HTML and JavaScript and I was wondering how to src to a file in a folder within a folder? 
Any help would be appreciated.

To be more specific I'm trying to access a JavaScript library in a folder named yui and which is another folder named libraries.

Comment: your question doeson't meet http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: because your question is not clear enough. you should specify more. and tell what you tried so far.

Comment: `src='libraries/yui/yourlibrary.js'`?

Comment: I wasn't sure where to start. I knew how to call a file, but I didn't know how to call a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src='./folderwithinfolder/file.js'></script>
```

To break it down:

`./` = folder this file is in.

`folderwithinfolder/`= A folder within the folder the webpage is in.

`file.js` = Javascript File.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the SRC to follow where you want to go the folders:

```
libraries/yui/your-library-name-here.js
```